# Zuul redirect to external link

Tags: spring, jhipster, http-redirect, netflix-zuul

Using zuul is possible to redirect a request to an external link like http://www.google.com ?

I have this scenario.

In a webpage there are a bunch of links pointing to a several websites. When you click to one of these zuul checks if you have the permission to visit this page and redirect the browser to the external link.

I've created a route filter.

```
public class TestZuulFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "route";
     }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
      return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        // ... filter logic ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {

         // ... permission check ...

         RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

         //todo redirect
    }
}
```

How can i redirect the user browser to google.com ?

Thank you.

**Update 20/09/2016**

I've managed to solve my problem changing filter type from "pre" to "post" and adding the Location HTTP header to the response.

```
public class TestZuulFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "post";
     }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
      return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        // ... filter logic ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {

         // ... permission check ...

         RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

         //redirect
         HttpServletResponse response = ctx.getResponse();
         response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);
         response.setHeader("Location", "http://www.google.com");

         return null;
    }
}
```

Now it works, but is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting at the http client level like this: https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/blob/1.x/zuul-netflix-webapp/src/main/groovy/filters/route/ZuulHostRequest.groovy#L161

Comment: Thank you Gael for you answer check the updated post. Tomorrow i will try the code that you've linked.